# Zero-sum team games with imperfect information

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, economics

I'm interested in the mathematical analysis of zero-sum games in which there are just two *sides* or *teams*, but multiple players on each team, who have *imperfect information* about the game state.  Bridge is perhaps the simplest example of such a game.  However, I'm specifically more interested in a version of a two-player [Colonel Blotto game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blotto_game) in which the two teams consist of players who don't necessarily know everything that is going on, or even what the other players on the same team are doing.  (My underlying thought is to tweak the Blotto game into a slightly more realistic model of real-world elections.)

Is there any prior literature on this topic? Finding the right search terms seems elusive. For example, I did find a paper on [A Blotto game with incomplete information](https://web.archive.org/web/20171209060633/https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/9665471.pdf) (Adamo and Matros, *Economics Letters* 105 (2009), 100–102) but that paper deals with $K$ non-cooperative players rather than two teams with multiple players on each team. There is another math.SE question that seems related, [Multiplayer cooperative game with imperfect information](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2925179), but in that setting, there is only one team and not two, and besides, the question was not answered.

Comment: I'm not aware of any paper doing that. In bridge players are uncertain about the hands of the other players. In the Blotto game that you have in mind, what is the source of uncertainty? Please, could you clarify that?

Comment: Also, the title is misleading. Zero-sum games are defined only  for two players. Even if you have only two teams, you still have to model it as having many players. The players in the same team have the same payoff function (but not the same information). Please could you change the title to add "team game" and remove the "zero sum" part?

Comment: @SergioParreiras Despite what Wikipedia may tell you, zero-sum games are not defined for only two players; in fact, von Neumann's 1928 paper explicitly considered multiplayer zero-sum games. But in any case, bridge is generally considered to be a two-"player" zero-sum game even though in some sense there are four "players." In the Blotto game, I'm imagining several variations, but for example, the players on a team might each have control of separate resources, and might not know the allocations chosen by other players.

Comment: I'm being intentionally somewhat vague about the setup of the Blotto game because I'd be interested in *any* analysis of something even remotely similar to what I'm describing here.

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding zero-sum games. In bridge, can two "players" in the same team coordinate about their strategy, share information, etc..? If not, I don't see how one could model a team as being one player.

Comment: The Matros' paper the source of uncertainty is the size of the budget. One could choose it to be the value of prizes. The later would be technically more difficult to carry out. There is a huge literature on team contests. I would search under "contest theory". Jing Feng Lu has an AER paper on it -I think it does not have incomplete information but it is dynamic. I would guess someone must have a team contest paper with incomplete info.

Comment: As for relating Blotto games to elections, Nicola Persico has an interesting paper that does that, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2938819 but it has no teams nor incomplete information.